# Enforce non-empty validation for AWS-Specific Parameter Types

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In my cloud formation template, I am using a few AWS-Specific Parameter Types. For example:

```
"VPC": {
      "Description": "Choose exiting VPC",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
},
```

allows the user who is deploying the stack to choose from a dropdown VPC list.

I noticed that if I were to not pick a VPC and leave that parameter blank, the stack *does* deploy, only to fail shortly afterwards because this parameter was left empty.

I went through the documentation here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

but did not find anything which explained this behavior.

---

Is there any way to enforce non-empty validation for these parameters (i.e. ensure that the user does choose a value) ? I would like to ensure that an error pops up as soon as one clicks `Create stack`. For normal parameters, I can use `AllowedPattern` to enforce a certain pattern. Is there anything similar for these parameter types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try and use a constraint on top of it.

Try [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=718587):

```
"AllowedPattern" : ".+"
```

Comment: Also if this still doesn't give you what you want, try setting `Default : ""`, not sure if that's allowed but if it is, and then they try and create the stack, the default value will violate the `.+` pattern.

Comment: At what stage this gives error to users. Does this give users error when try to move beyond parameters screen without mentioning parameter or when they try to create stack at final screen.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to an [`AllowedPattern`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-properties) of `.+` which will result in `Parameter 'VPC' must match pattern .+` before stack deployment, you can also try CloudFormation Template Constraint Rules:

https://www.cloudar.be/awsblog/undocumented-feature-using-template-constraint-rules-in-cloudformation

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/how-to-perform-cross-parameter-validation-using-aws-cloudformation-rules-and-assertions/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/adminguide/reference-template_constraint_rules.html

Comment: I like that too! Nice little feature didn't know about that one.

Comment: Cheers Pat, that works! Could you expand your answer to include a full example with rules? Rules are probably overkill here if a simple `AllowedPattern` can be used, but I'd like to see a full answer instead of just links because often those break; for the future readers.